# How to implement characters method using SAXParser on Android

Tags: xml, android, parsing

I am parsing xml using the SAXParser and want to know if this is the right way to implement the characters method.

Assume there's a class-level String variable named elementValue and it is initialized to "" in the startElement method.

Here is the characters method:

```
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
{
    String charsToAppend = new String(ch, start, length);
    elementValue = elementValue + charsToAppend;    
}
```

Is it correct that we need to append to the value we have so far and is the append being done correctly?

Also, why does the characters method give the start index?  Won't it be zero every time?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `elementValue` a type of and where is it initialized?

Comment: It's just a class-level variable in the class that extends DefaultHandler.  It's initialized in the startElement method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you need to append because there is no guarantee that the chunk of data read will contain all of the element text.

The start position is given and needs to be used because the other characters in the array can be junk.

However, you should use a `StringBuffer` instead, and call its' `append()` method, like so:

```
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
  yourStringBuffer.append(ch, start, length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll switch to using a StringBuffer.  But out of curiosity, why wouldn't the parser just send a "clean" array instead?

Comment: The design provides the parser with the ability to read characters into a buffer, and select part of that buffer to be passed to the application via the characters() method. This provides the potential efficiency of not having to produce a new String object which might be discarded by the application.

Comment: Actually the code for appending to the StringBuffer (or StringBuilder) should be:

yourStringBuffer.append(ch, start, length);

Comment: Paul, thanks for the explanation and correction for the append call.