# Sax parser with DefaultHandler implementing LexicalHandler

Tags: java, xml-parsing, sax

I have a handler with this signature:

```
class XMLReaderHandler extends DefaultHandler implements LexicalHandler
```

I'm using it with a sax parser ( javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser )

Is it possible that in case of empty tag like `<id></id>` the parser is not calling the method

```
characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException
```

It's what I'm getting in debug in presence of an empty tag. I still need to do the characters thing because I want to add an empty string in that case.

PS: don't suggest XPath because I'm already using it, I'm implementing it with Sax in case I need to process big data.

Thanks

EDIT:

So some new info. I'm using in my schema the `xs:anyType` with `processContents="skip"`. Apparently SaxParser will skip things like that, so I found that I could use something like:

```
saxParserFactory.setFeature(
"http://java.sun.com/xml/schema/features/report-ignored-element-content-whitespace", 
true);
```

but it's giving me `org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature 'http://java.sun.com/xml/schema/features/report-ignored-element-content-whitespace' is not recognized.`

Comment: what are you doing with the characters method? are you saving the characters to a buffer (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2224356/217324) ?

Comment: Not really. I'm storing a map of value. Right now I've solved using a StringBuilder in the startElement so I'll have an empty string. But I would like to have null if characters is not called.